# Integrating Activiti Explorer with Ruby on Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, mechanize, activiti

I have tried several different methods to accomplish this and none have been successful. Ive tried jruby, the rest api for activiti (this does not update the UI and is thus not suited for my purposes), and the mechanize gem. The mechanize gem did not work because of the VAADIN UI that activiti explorer ships with or so I think. I currently have activiti hosted in an iframe in my rails app, and am trying to find a way to communicate between the two. I used the gem like this:

```
agent= Mechanize.new
agent.redirection_limit= 10
//page is used three times to illustrate different routes taken.
page= agent.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/activiti-webapp-explorer2-5.18.0/)

page= agent.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/activiti-webapp-explorer2-5.18.0/ui/APP/2/login',{'username'=>'kermit', 'password'=>'kermit'} )

page=agent.put('http://127.0.0.1:8080/activiti-webapp-explorer2-5.18.0/ui/1/loginHandler',{'username'=>'kermit', 'password'=>'kermit'})
```

here is a sample response from activiti explorer when mechanize is used:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<style type="text/css">html, body {height:100%;margin:0;}</style><link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="/activiti-webapp-explorer2-5.18.0/VAADIN/themes/activiti/favicon.ico" /><link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="/activiti-webapp-explorer2-5.18.0/VAADIN/themes/activiti/favicon.ico" /><title>Activiti&#32;Explorer</title>
</head>
<body scroll="auto" class="v-generated-body">
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if(!vaadin || !vaadin.vaadinConfigurations) {
 if(!vaadin) { var vaadin = {}} 
vaadin.vaadinConfigurations = {};
if (!vaadin.themesLoaded) { vaadin.themesLoaded = {}; }
}
vaadin.vaadinConfigurations["activitiwebappexplorer25180ui-1091631569"] = {appUri:'/activiti-webapp-explorer2-5.18.0/ui', standalone: true, themeUri:"/activiti-webapp-explorer2-5.18.0/VAADIN/themes/activiti", versionInfo : {vaadinVersion:"6.8.8",applicationVersion:"NONVERSIONED"},"comErrMsg": {"caption":"Communication problem","message" : "Take note of any unsaved data, and <u>click here<\/u> to continue.","url" : null},"authErrMsg": {"caption":"Authentication problem","message" : "Take note of any unsaved data, and <u>click here<\/u> to continue.","url" : null}};
//]]>
</script>
<iframe tabIndex='-1' id='__gwt_historyFrame' style='position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0;overflow:hidden;' src='javascript:false'></iframe>
<script language='javascript' src='/activiti-webapp-explorer2-5.18.0/VAADIN/widgetsets/org.activiti.explorer.CustomWidgetset/org.activiti.explorer.CustomWidgetset.nocache.js?1444407987049'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if(!vaadin.themesLoaded['activiti']) {
var stylesheet = document.createElement('link');
stylesheet.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
stylesheet.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
stylesheet.setAttribute('href', '/activiti-webapp-explorer2-5.18.0/VAADIN/themes/activiti/styles.css');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(stylesheet);
vaadin.themesLoaded['activiti'] = true;
}
//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
setTimeout('if (typeof org_activiti_explorer_CustomWidgetset == "undefined") {alert("Failed to load the widgetset: /activiti-webapp-explorer2-5.18.0/VAADIN/widgetsets/org.activiti.explorer.CustomWidgetset/org.activiti.explorer.CustomWidgetset.nocache.js?1444407987049")};',15000);
//]]>
</script>
<div id="activitiwebappexplorer25180ui-1091631569" class="v-app v-theme-activiti v-app-ExplorerApp" ><div class="v-app-loading"></div></div>
<noscript>You have to enable javascript in your browser to use an application    built with Vaadin.</noscript></body>
    </html>
```

I have tried all of the possible url's I could see on the UI, but none of them work. I have tried all of post, get, and put with each of these three urls .I found these URL's by looking at the loaded page, and noticing that they are nested iframes. Any help in seeing the feasiblity of the mechanize gem would be great, as feel as if this would be an easy fix to my problem. As a side note, I have changed the tomcat properties to allow for CORS requests. Also, http requests from rails to activiti explorer do not work either, so that form of communication is also out.

Also if you are familiar with activiti- I have edited the authenticate method in default login handler to try and parse http requests to get the username and password to login automatically. This however returns the same html code as printed above. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is a sample of the http requests I make from rails:

```
auth = {:userid=> "kermit", :password => "kermit"}
puts HTTParty.get("http://activiti.testing.com:8080/activiti-webapp-explorer2-5.18.0/", :content_type => "application/json",
:basic_auth => auth)
```

Comment: I´ve managed to sucessfully integrate Activiti REST  with PHP web frontend, so integrating with a RoR app should not be much different. Can you give more details on the problems you had with this approach ?

Comment: I have no problem using activiti REST, since thats handled by a gem. The problem is that the UI does not have anything to do with REST, and the UI is the most important part of the integration.

Comment: Ok, but your UI is going to display information about processes and allow the end user to interact with them somehow, right ? A tipical scenario ir to create a customized inbox for a given business process, or accomplish a collaborative task (one that requires multiple review/approve steps, por instance).
In those cases, what I´ve done is to create a custom UI using some SPA framework (Angular/Ember/etc) and consume all backend information via REST calls straight to Activiti, with no direct backend integration.

Comment: I want to use the activiti explorer front end because it already configured for most of my needs. My custom tasks require that I send information to my ROR webapp and then be able to receive back some information. Using rest I am able to interact from rails to activiti, however I also need to ensure that the UI is also updated with the rest calls. Both rest and explorer are using the same database, but what I need right now is just to display that.

Comment: When you say "ensure that the UI is also updated" you mean the explorer UI which is loaded in yout RoR UI as a iframe ? My feeling is that you´re going to be in an eternal fight (read: "as long as you´re involved in this project") with both apps. You can try a simple "reload" on the iframe or maybe some sort of polling mechanism, but I´d  really, really consider one of the following two approaches:1) If explorer is really close to your needs, add the missing features to it.2) Otherwise, write your own UI in RoR and use REST on the browser or server in order to create your app.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I will try what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think integrating Activiti Explorer in iframe is not a good idea. Since your username and password are exposed! And the requirements of the frontend are various.

I like Activiti Explorer at first, Modeler is really awesone! But I use Rails and find it hard to customize and integrate Activiti Explorer later. I tried integrate with Activiti REST, while I prefer Activiti Java API for the following reasons:

1. Activiti REST is a subset of Activiti Java API. eg: `SetProcessDefinitionVersionCmd` is not availiable in Activiti REST.
2. Performance concerns. I develop a task web page, but it needs over 10 http requests.
3. I like Acitivi Modeler and Diagram Viewer. I need Activiti Explorer running and make them work together.

So I develop a gem named [jruby_activiti](https://github.com/richfisher/jruby_activiti), integrating Activiti Engine, Modeler and Diagram Viewer. All these are availiable in JRuby on Rails! Hope my experiences could help you.